# Xubuntu 18.04 wrong time with dual boot Windows 10

Tags: boot, time

Whenever I boot into Windows after Xubuntu the time is wrong. In Xubuntu 16.04 I had to set Xubuntu to use local time with

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

but apparently this don't work in 18.04. Time is still wrong when I boot into Windows. Any ideas ?

Comment: I have my system setup to force Windows to use UTC like Linux instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Windows 10 to use UTC Time instead of the default Local Time. Use Regedit and create an entry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal`

For 64-bit Windows use QWORD and 32-bit Windows use DWORD. Set the value to 1.